# Existe alguma forma de fazer um foreach com duas variáveis ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: php

Tentei fazer separando por vírgula, mas não funcionou:

```
foreach($dados as $d, $telefones as $t){}
```

Sei que existem outras formas de fazer este `foreach` que funcionam, mas queria tirar esta curiosidade. É possível usar duas variáveis em um `foreach` usando PHP?

Comment: qual relação existe entre `$dados` e `$telefones` ?

Comment: Os dois tem um identificador em comum. Existe `$dados->ra` e `$telefones->ra`

Comment: Relacionado : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Se se tratar de dois *arrays*, pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
foreach(array_combine($dados, $telefones) as $d => $t)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu sei que a pergunta já foi respondida, mas creio que a resposta atual atenda somente à casos onde o primeiro `array` contenha somente números ou string. Pois se tiver um `Object` ou `Array`, `array_combine` irá falhar.

## Array_map

Na verdade, não se trata de um `foreach`, mas se trata de um `loop` com quantos arrays você quiser ao mesmo tempo!

A solução minha para isso é com `array_map`.

Veja a mágica:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];

$b = [4, 5, 6];

$c = [6, 7, 8];



array_map(function ($v1, $v2, $v3) {
    echo $v1, $v2, $v3, PHP_EOL;

}, $a, $b, $c);
```

A saída será:

```
146
257
368
```

Veja um exemplo:

https://ideone.com/aSEM9i

## Foreach com `list`

Além do exemplo já citado, gostaria também de deixar demonstrado aqui que o PHP, a partir da versão 5.5, possui um novo recurso: Usar `list` no `foreach`.

Veja:

```
foreach ([$a, $b, $c] as list ($value1, $value2, $value3)) {

        echo $value1, $value2, $value3, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Nesse caso o resultado seria:

```
123
456
678
```